# How to Set Linux server Wordpress Plugin or Themes download server ask FTP hostname , FTP Username , FTP password .?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to Set Linux server Wordpress Plugin or Themes download server ask FTP hostname , FTP Username , FTP password ?

see given link :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/stkot.png

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/stkot.png]

Comment: You need to set the same as you normaly use to install WordPress in first place.

Comment: Sorry dear it not working ......

Answer (score 1):

This one will work. I have used this for my Ubuntu machine that uses SSH keys

http://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/

Just upload this plugin via FTP. Activate it and then enter your details. Mine uses SSH keys. It supports all the options. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your wp-config.php file.

```
// ** FTP SETTINGS FOR AUTO-UPDATE ** //
define('FTP_HOST', 'localhost');
define('FTP_USER', 'USERNAME');
define('FTP_PASS', 'PASSWORD');
```